# typewritting issue with array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to produce type writer like animation for array of words using windows timeout function. But everytime i run the code it is prininting only first letter of each word.
Please help me in solving the error.

```js
var numbers = ['lambda','sql'];

function typeWriter() {
    numbers.forEach(function(obj,index) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            var i=0;
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="";
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (obj.charAt(i));
            i++;
            },50);
        }, 5000 * (index + 1));
    });
}
```

```html
<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick=" typeWriter()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You might want to checkout `setInterval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following code to animate like Typewriter

```js
var strings = ['Welcome','to', 'StackOverflow'];

function typeWriter() {
    var p = document.getElementById("demo");
    var i = 0;

    p.innerHTML = '';
    strings.forEach(function(string, index) {     
        string.split("").forEach(function(char, charIndex){
            i++;
            setTimeout(function() {
                p.innerHTML += char;
            }, 50*i);
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            p.innerHTML += ' ';
        }, 50*i);
    });
}
```

```html
<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick=" typeWriter()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```